# SQL Case Evaluation fails?

Tags: sql-server

first time poster, long time user of the website, anyway here goes.

The value in column 'Form Factor' in the CASE statement. when the value is 15, it defaults to the ELSE value.

I've tried with single quotes, wildcarding it, and as you can see at the bottom I've even tried using values from other columns. When the 'Form Factor' value is 15, the column 'Model' contains the word 'Desk' in it. CASE Statement STILL displays the ELSE value as unknown. What gives?

```sql
SELECT 
v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Name0 AS 'Hostname',

v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Manufacturer0 AS 'Make',

v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Model0 AS 'Model',

CASE 

    WHEN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0 = '8' THEN 'Laptop'
    WHEN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0 = '9' THEN 'Laptop'
    WHEN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0 = '10' THEN 'Laptop'
    WHEN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0 = '11' THEN 'Laptop'
    WHEN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0 = '12' THEN 'Laptop'
    WHEN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0 = '14' THEN 'Laptop'
    WHEN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0 = '18' THEN 'Laptop'
    WHEN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0 = '3' THEN 'Desktop'
    WHEN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0 = '4' THEN 'Desktop'
    WHEN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0 = '5' THEN 'Desktop'
    WHEN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0 = '6' THEN 'Desktop'
    WHEN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0 = '7' THEN 'Desktop'
    WHEN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0 = '15' THEN 'Desktop'
    WHEN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0 = '16' THEN 'Desktop'
    WHEN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0 = '23' THEN 'Desktop'
    WHEN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0 = '30' THEN 'Tablet'
    WHEN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0 = '31' THEN 'Tablet'
    WHEN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0 = '32' THEN 'Tablet'
    WHEN 'Model' LIKE '%Desk%' THEN 'Desktop'
    WHEN 'Model' LIKE 'HP ProDesk%' THEN 'Desktop'
    Else 'Unknown'
    END AS 'Form Factor',


v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.Caption0 AS 'Operating System'

FROM

v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM

INNER JOIN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE ON v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID=v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ResourceID

Inner Join v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM ON v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.ResourceID=v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID

Where 

v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.Caption0 Like '%Windows 7%' 

OR v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.Caption0 Like '%Windows 10%' 

OR v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.Caption0 Like '%Windows XP%' 

OR v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.Caption0 Like '%Windows Vista%'
```

Comment: I would suggest the value in the table isn't what you think it is (especially if you're storing numerical data as a `varchar`).

Comment: Thank you Larnu, but then why do all of the other WHEN statements work?

Comment: Because those values *do* match. If the clause `= '15'` isn't being met, it's because ilthe column doesn't have the value `'15'`.

Comment: Fair enough, but the "WHEN 'Model' LIKE '%Desk%' THEN 'Desktop'" SHould then catch it, but it doesn't, and its only on THOSE lines where the '15' failed.

Comment: Remove the single quotes from Model.

Comment: @AnthonyC the clause `WHEN 'Model' LIKE '%Desk%'` can **never** be true. The literal string `'Model'` looks nothing like the literal string `'desk'`; the most they share is the letter `e`.

Comment: I see what you folks are saying. I removed the single quotes from 'Model' and it worked. it was looking at the literal string and not the Column name. Thank you!